# How do you align column values and keep the association of all columns to the right of column C with column C?

Tags: excel-formula

I am using =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0))) to align column values, but I would like to keep the association of all columns to the right of column C with column C.

Comment: I don't follow your question fully.  Can you provide an example or screen shot?

Comment: I have data by ID number in a spreadsheet. I want to associate that data with another spreadsheet that has the same ID number in another spreadsheet. So, what I really need is more than I am asking with this question. I tried to insert a screen shot here but could not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to input the other corresponding columns from the first spreadsheet (Table1) to the matching rows on the second spreadsheet (Table2) by the ID number (Column C in Table1). I think you pretty much have the resolution in your first column with a little adaptation. In Table2 to output your subsequent column (ie column D from Table 1) have the following formulas:

> =IF(ISNA(MATCH($A1,Table1!$C:$C,0)),"",INDEX(Table1!D:D,MATCH($A1,Table1!$C:$C,0)))

The same as your previous column but instead of outputting the ID number that you are matching to, it outputs the column next to it in the same row. You can then replicate this for as many columns as your first table has. Hope this is what you need. Cheers,